# How to use Filezilla SFTP with root disabled?

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, sftp, root

CentOS 7, I have root disabled for obvious reasons, and because of this I cannot use Filezilla SFTP as folders are denied to other users.

I added a user to the 'wheel' group successfully, but although it connects, I cannot get into the folders (specifically the error logs) because I am not root.

Is there a way to modify a user so that FileZilla or any other FTP program will allow FTP to the home folder?

Comment: I can get into SFTP since adding user to wheel, but I can't move from the folder I am in without the error:                                                            

Directory /home: permission denied
Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing

Comment: It is unclear what folder or files are you going to access. By default, /home directory is accessible for everyone to see its content

Comment: You should not need `root` access for SFTP (you probably do something wrong), but if you really need to, you can allow only public key authentication for `root`, which is quite safe.

Comment: @OlegBolden I need to access the /var/www folders, etc.

Comment: I'd recommend removing unpriviledged user from the `wheel` group.
To access files in /var/www folder and it subfolders under `user` account set this ACL:
`setfacl -Rm d:u:user:rwX,u:user:rwX /var/www`

Comment: @OlegBolden - I still user the wheel user for SSH, but it's just filezilla that gave me the issues. I don't want to enable root just for SFTP. I will give what you wrote a shot.

Comment: @OlegBolden Please submit that as an answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As [betrieb](https://superuser.com/users/461558/bertieb) suggested I submit my comment as an answer.

To access files in `/var/www` folder and it subfolders under `user` account set this ACL (you need root priviledges to do it):

```
setfacl -Rm d:u:user:rwX,u:user:rwX /var/www
```